# Adding a plane to scatterplot3d

Tags: r, scatter-plot, scatter, plane, scatter3d

```
x <-rnorm(500,50,2)
y <-rnorm(500,5,1)
z <-rnorm(500,6,1)

s3d <- scatterplot3d(x[z<6], y[z<6], z[z<6], zlim=range(z),  color="darkgrey", col.axis="blue",col.grid="lightblue",   main="scatterplot3d - 1", pch=20)
s3d$plane3d(6,0,0)
s3d$points3d(x[z>=6], y[z>=6], z[z>=6], pch=20)
```

The above code tells me how to add a plane 'z=6' to the 3d scatter plot.

The first question is:
I'm wondering how to add a plane such as 'x=3' or 'y=2'.

R help file explains that

```
plane3d(Intercept, x.coef = NULL, y.coef = NULL, lty = "dashed", lty.box = NULL, ...). Instead of Intercept a vector containing 3 elements can be specified.
```

The second question is:
I also wonder what the 'vector with 3 elements' instead of Intercept does and what is the role of x.coef and y.coef argument.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: I would use a linear model to add planes, as I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550501/adding-a-plane-to-a-scatterplot3d/33180375#33180375) and as the package authors use in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterplot3d/vignettes/s3d.pdf):

```
plot3d <- scatterplot3d(x, y, z, ... )
model  <- lm(y ~ x + z)
plot3d$plane3d(model)
```

You can specify the xyz intercepts manually, but I don't recommend it, as it produces somewhat odd behaviour. You can also construct complex mesh surfaces using the function intended for points, but as the authors state in the vignette:

> Note that scatterplot3d is designed to generate scatter plots,  not to
>   draw  surfaces,  is  not  really  user friendly  for this  purpose, 
>   for which we'd typically rather use R's persp function.

Question 2: The vector with three elements is a container for the xyz intercepts. You can specify them manually as you did above with `s3d$plane3d(6,0,0)`. The x and y coefficients appear to be for mapping those two variables onto a plane.

To make specific planes manually, here is a suggestion from [Uwe](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Multiple-planes-in-a-scatterplot3d-td4399234.html) himself:

```
spd <- scatterplot3d(1:10, 1:10, 1:10)

# xy
spd$plane3d(0.3549896,0,0,lty="dotted")

# yz
x0 <- 5
xyz1 <- spd$xyz.convert(rep(x0, 6), rep(0, 6), seq(0, 10, by=2))
xyz2 <- spd$xyz.convert(rep(x0, 6), rep(10, 6), seq(0, 10, by=2))
segments(xyz1$x, xyz1$y, xyz2$x, xyz2$y, lty="dotted")

xyz1 <- spd$xyz.convert(rep(x0, 6), seq(0, 10, by=2), rep(0, 6))
xyz2 <- spd$xyz.convert(rep(x0, 6), seq(0, 10, by=2), rep(10, 6))
segments(xyz1$x, xyz1$y, xyz2$x, xyz2$y, lty="dotted")

# zx
y0 <- 6
xyz1 <- spd$xyz.convert(rep(0, 6), rep(y0, 6), seq(0, 10, by=2))
xyz2 <- spd$xyz.convert(rep(10, 6), rep(y0, 6), seq(0, 10, by=2))
segments(xyz1$x, xyz1$y, xyz2$x, xyz2$y, lty="dotted")

xyz1 <- spd$xyz.convert(seq(0, 10, by=2), rep(y0, 6), rep(0, 6))
xyz2 <- spd$xyz.convert(seq(0, 10, by=2), rep(y0, 6), rep(10, 6))
segments(xyz1$x, xyz1$y, xyz2$x, xyz2$y, lty="dotted")
```

The points are first sampled at a regular interval matching the grid in xyz space using their built-in xyz coordinate conversion function, before mapping the segments between them, producing grids:

[image]