# Draw a vertical wall over a specified $(x,y)$ curve in plot3D in R

Tags: r, plot3d

I have a set of coordinate pairs `(x,y)` that characterize a curve (made of linear segments), such as `x=c(1,2,3,4,5)` and `y=c(1,2,3,2,1)`. I imagine this curve "lies on the ground" (at `z=0`), and I wish to draw a vertical wall above the curve. My `z` axis is between `0` and `1`, and I want the wall to cover this entire interval, so that the wall divides my 3D box into two parts. Specifically,

- The first segment of my wall has these four corners: (1,1,0), (1,1,1), (2,2,0), (2,2,1).
- The next segment has these four corners: (2,2,0), (2,2,1), (3,3,0), (3,3,1).
- The third segment has these four corners: (3,3,0), (3,3,1), (4,2,0), (4,2,1).
- The last segment has these four corners: (4,2,0), (4,2,1), (5,1,0), (5,1,1).

To see the line on the ground, use this:

```r
x=c(1,2,3,4,5)
y=c(1,2,3,2,1)
plot(x,y,type="b")
```

I want a vertical wall above, done in 3D using `plot3D` in R. How could I do this?

(Using the function `surface3d`, I can draw a surface over a mesh of `(x,y)`. However, here I do not have a mesh, I have a single curve. Moreover, for every pair of my `(x,y)` coordinates, `z` is an entire interval `[0,1]` instead of just a point.)

Comment: Isn’t there a `plane3d`?

Comment: @IRTFM, my wall is not necessarily a plane. The line on the ground may be a curve. I have edited for clarity. (Not being a native speaker, I forgot that a line is not the same as a curve.)

Comment: Then I agree with the downvote that the question is too vague and lacks an [MCVE] resulting in a vague and useless question. Use SO’s [edit] facilities to improve your question.

Comment: @IRTFM, I wish I had an example! I can give an example of `x` and `y`, but that is all I have. What else would be needed in a reproducible example? And I wonder what exactly is vague about my question? I think mathematically my description of the wall is complete. Is it not?

Comment: Whether my guess at what you are asking is going to meet requirements would need consideration of a numerical example at minimum. Use code to draw the curve.

Comment: @IRTFM, I have now included a numerical example.

Comment: Richard you may find this R-specific guide to a minimal reproducible example helpful: [How to write a good R question with a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure using `plot3D`, but using `rgl` (which `plot3Drgl` supports), it's easy.

Just draw a sequence of triangles or quadrilaterals over it.  For example, suppose your line is a semicircle of radius 1, and you want the wall to be 1 unit high:

```
library(rgl)
theta <- seq(0, pi, len=100)
x <- cos(theta)
y <- sin(theta)

# Construct the boundary

x1 <- c(x, rev(x))
y1 <- c(y, rev(y))
z1 <- c(rep(0, length(x)), rep(1, length(x)))
xyz <- cbind(x1, y1, z1)
lines3d(xyz)

# Quads are elements (1, 2, 199, 200), (2, 3, 198, 199), etc

idx <- as.numeric(t(cbind(1:99, 2:100, 199:101, 200:102)))
quads3d(xyz, indices=idx, col = "red")

# add axes

decorate3d()
```

[image]

Comment: This works! I was able to adapt it to my case. (I will wait for a while before accepting your answer just in case someone posts an ever better one.)