# R lattice wireframe/cloud map colors with other columns, not x/y/z

Tags: r

everyone, I am using R lattice **cloud/wireframe** functions to create 3D scatter plot. But I found it can only use the **y** column to draw a color key legend and color the points. So how should I map the color with other column? Thanks!

Answers for the questions or code

Comment: Need [MCVE] assuming you have not yet done a thorough search. Seems likely this has been asked and answered though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774777/how-to-change-points-and-add-a-regression-to-a-cloudplot-using-r